# Parse data-i18n attributes in html element

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, i18next

I am trying to parse 'data-i18n' attributes from html files with custom regex (also with the default i18n.t function):

```
i18next modules/ -o lang/ -r '[^a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:t)|(?:i18n\\.t)|(?:data-i18n))(?:\\(|\\s|=)\\s*(?:(?:\'((?:(?:\\\\\')?[^\']+)+[^\\\\])\')|(?:"((?:(?:\\\\")?[^"]+)+[^\\\\])"))'
```

The parser can be found here:
https://github.com/karellm/i18next-parser

The command from the docs:

```
i18next /path/to/file/or/dir -r "(.*)"
```

The regex has been tested on regexpal and debuggex, it maches the proper tags:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:t)|(?:i18n\.t)|(?:data-i18n))(?:\(|\s|=)\s*(?:(?:'((?:(?:\\')?[^']+)+[^\\])')|(?:"((?:(?:\\")?[^"]+)+[^\\])"))
```

I tried escaping the regex string in various forms, but it's not working. 
How to do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using gulp as following:

```
var i18next = require("i18next-parser");
var gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("i18next-parse", function () {
    gulp.src("js/modules/**")
        .pipe(i18next({locales: ['en', 'hu'],
            parser: '[^a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:t)|(?:i18n\\.t)|(?:data-i18n))(?:\\(|\\s|=)\\s*(?:(?:\'((?:(?:\\\\\')?[^\']+)+[^\\\\])\')|(?:"((?:(?:\\\\")?[^"]+)+[^\\\\])"))',
            output: "js/lang"})
            .on('reading', function(path) {
                console.log("Reading: " + path);
            })
            .on('writing', function(path) {
                console.log("Writing: " + path);
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/lang'));
});
```

You can pass the regex this way (which was the problem when you were trying to pass in the command line).